# Drupal & PayPal Module - Read Credentials from file?

Tags: php, drupal, paypal, drupal-7, paypal-sandbox

I have a production_db and a copy of it, a test_db, where I develop, test new feature, solve problems, ecc. So, sometimes I copy the production_db on the test_db, but here's the problem: I know that Api Username, Password and Signature are stored in the rules_config table, in the data column of type blob, so when i do a copy of the DB, these configuration were copied, and i have to enter in the PDC, go to the PayPal Module settings (both PayPal Express Checkout for PayPal account and credit Card) and then change the values of the API with the sandbox account one.

The question is: I need a way to read PayPal's credentials from a configuration file instead of DB, but I don't know how and if it's possible. I tried to figure out how this data are collected and used in the deep of Drupal, so i can intercept the DB call and put me in the middle of it, but with no success.

Someone have or had the same problem?

Thanks a lot to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

First Identify where your database call is happening, I guess that should be in your PAYPAL module.

Write one YAML file to store your paypal credentials. Now use the YAML function to get contents from the files. Drupal supports YAML naturally.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor!symfony!yaml!Yaml.php/function/Yaml%3A%3Aparse/8.2.x

Hope this helps.